# How to enforce invariants on vuex state

Tags: vuex

As an invariant I want to ensure that the state in my vuex store (actually in one of the modules) must always be valid according to a JSON schema. Since the mutations are the atomic operations on the state, the validation should be performed at the end of a mutation function.

One Option I considered is putting some code inside every mutation in order to achieve this invariant. So every mutation would look something like this:

```
const setPostTitle = (state, { title }) {
  const postBefore = _.deepClone(state.post)
  state.post.title = title
  if (!validate(state.post)) {
    state.post = postBefore
  }
}
```

I can encapsulate this into a higher order function, but everyone needs to be aware to add it to every method that mutates anything on the `state.post`.

I thought another option would be to use a plugin, however plugins are only supported for the store but not in modules (see https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/467). Anyways if possible, this solution would look roughly like this:

```
export const validatePostPlugin = store => {
  let lastValidPostState = {}

  store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
    if (!validate(state.post)) {
      console.error('Validation failed')
      store.commit('setPost', lastValidPostState)
    } else {
      lastValidPostState = _.deepClone(state.post)
    }
  })
}
```

I don't like it because it always needs to hold a copy of the entire state (which is not critical here but might be really large) and it also completely replaces the post state if validation fails.

Is there a better way?